# I need to add "Import Schema" button to the Survey Creator

Tags: surveyjs

I want my users to be able to easily create new survey forms from a library of existing templates.  I don't see a way to enable this from within the Survey Creator interface.  Is this already built in?

I'm using these creator options.

```
        const creatorOptions = {
            showLogicTab: true,
            showSidebar: true,
            showThemeTab: true,
            showPreviewTab: false,
            showPagesInPreviewTab: true,
            showSimulatorInPreviewTab: true,
            showSurveyTitle: true,
            showJSONEditorTab: false,
            showHeaderInEmptySurvey: true,
            showTitlesInExpressions: true,
            allowChangeThemeInPreview: true,
            allowModifyPages: true,
            themeForPreview: "modern",
            designerHeight: "",
            isAutoSave: true
        };
```

Comment: What is your button expected to do?